# Implementing different sized containers inside a SingleChildScrollView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image]

Is there a way to implement the above inside a SingleChildScrollView randomly? as in not manually configure each container one at a time?

Comment: It would make more sense to use a `ListView.builder` and then have some randomized (maybe seeded by `i` ) code in the itemBuilder Function `(context, int i)=> Widget` in my opinion.

Comment: Check this one: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view

Answer (score 1):

You can achive this my using flutter_staggered_grid_view
Apply this plugin `flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.4.1`

**Full code**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/flutter_staggered_grid_view.dart';

const List<StaggeredTile> _staggeredTiles = <StaggeredTile>[
  StaggeredTile.count(2, 2),
  StaggeredTile.count(2, 1),
  StaggeredTile.count(1, 2),
  StaggeredTile.count(1, 1),
  StaggeredTile.count(2, 2),
  StaggeredTile.count(1, 2),
  StaggeredTile.count(1, 1),
  StaggeredTile.count(3, 1),
  StaggeredTile.count(1, 1),
  StaggeredTile.count(4, 1),
];

const List<Widget> _tiles = <Widget>[
  _Example01Tile(Colors.green, Icons.widgets),
  _Example01Tile(Colors.lightBlue, Icons.wifi),
  _Example01Tile(Colors.amber, Icons.panorama_wide_angle),
  _Example01Tile(Colors.brown, Icons.map),
  _Example01Tile(Colors.deepOrange, Icons.send),
  _Example01Tile(Colors.indigo, Icons.airline_seat_flat),
  _Example01Tile(Colors.red, Icons.bluetooth),
  _Example01Tile(Colors.pink, Icons.battery_alert),
  _Example01Tile(Colors.purple, Icons.desktop_windows),
  _Example01Tile(Colors.blue, Icons.radio),
];

class Example01 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('example 01'),
        ),
        body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 12),
            child: StaggeredGridView.count(
              crossAxisCount: 4,
              staggeredTiles: _staggeredTiles,
              mainAxisSpacing: 4,
              crossAxisSpacing: 4,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
              children: _tiles,
            )));
  }
}

class _Example01Tile extends StatelessWidget {
  const _Example01Tile(this.backgroundColor, this.iconData);

  final Color backgroundColor;
  final IconData iconData;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      color: backgroundColor,
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {},
        child: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
            child: Icon(
              iconData,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

*Change the `List<StaggeredTile> _staggeredTiles` to change the tiles property and `List<Widget> _tiles` for the widgest that need to be appeared you can use containers here for showing twitter, apple etc... as well as colour, gradent.. etc*

Thank you